# Evaluating LaTeX input

Tags: workflow

I frequently use desmos, and when I copy equations and expressions, desmos gives these in LaTeX. Is it possible for sagemath to interpret the LaTeX code and make a sagemath object of it?

Say for example i have the LaTeX expression:

$$\frac{ab+\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}-1}}{a^{2}-1}$$

Then I would like to get something I can paste into sagemath:

```
a*b = (a*b + sqrt(a^2 b^2 - 1))/(a^2 - 1)
```

I already found [this](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/25870/latex-input/) question on the sagemath ask page which the answer was that there really was not anything like it in sagemath, but that you could make it. I managed to adapt the code so that it works in the test cases given, (it was written in python2 code) but it seemed like it did not work consistently, and notably was missing the inclusing of evaluating expressions with \frac fractions. [Here](https://f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)=x%5E%7B3%7D-10%20%5Ccdot%20x%5E%7B2%7D+31x-30) is a link for a sage cell to run the code with the example given in the answer from the ask page. I was messing with notebooks, so I also made this notebook on cocalc with the code. [cocalc](https://cocalc.com/projects/1c826df7-4e1d-4c6b-abec-23778196c143/files/)

[This](https://pastebin.com/SLRQCt4V) is a pastebin of the code of the orginal answer I adapted. I also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650941/fastest-way-to-compute-a-determinant-from-a-latex-matrix-input) post, but this one was more in the direction of specifically calculating a determinant given a matrix.

If no such thing exists, (which I kinda do think is the case) then I am curious for an alternative of quickly moving between expressions in LaTeX (or desmos specifically), instead of just typing the entire expression out. Since desmos uses mathjax, possibly there is some software that reverses mathjax output?

I already posted on the math exchange, I hope this is the right place for this question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're familiar with how TeX works, not necessarily with how SageMath work. But well, maybe just leave it there and someone may happen to be good at SageMath.

Comment: How is SageMath supposed to tell whether `ab` is a variable on its own or instead represents `a * b`? There are almost certainly other ambiguities in LaTeX that may be difficult or impossible to resolve.

Comment: I understand that indeed there is no perfect solution, in your example I would say that it should seperate the letters as different variables. An edit was made to my original post that removed the star signs. I guess the reason that I think it should be possible is the fact that symbolab and desmos can communicate equations (pretty much flawlessly) by copying and pasting the corresponding code, so I thought maybe they both used some sort of standard way of "decoding" LaTeX equations.

Comment: I don't think this has been done. IMO, ask your question at the AskSagemath site referencing the question you linked to above. Since the question and answer are about 8 years old, it's possible there has been some progress. Perhaps the person with the answer there has made some progress on this that they are willing to share.